# Упрощение sql запроса. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно упростить sql запрос.

```sql
SELECT
    r.id,
    (
    SELECT
        STRING_VALUE
    FROM
        journal_field_data f
    WHERE
        r.id = f.journal_record_id
        AND field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB' ) AS str_val
FROM
    INTERSHOP.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
WHERE
    r.edit_state = 0
    AND r.journal_id = 515
    AND r.journal_table_id = 1
ORDER BY
    r.PRIMARY_DATE DESC;
```

Как можно вытащить из этого запроса поле, собираемое в `str_val`, чтобы был не подзапрос, а в виде `join`? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: ну вот прямо `join journal_field_data f on r.id = f.journal_record_id
          AND field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB'`

Comment: через `left join`, а в остальном как описано выше, пользователем Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так?

```sql
SELECT
    r.id
FROM
    INTERSHOP.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
LEFT JOIN journal_field_data f ON
    (r.id = f.journal_record_id
    AND field_name = 'SERTIF_NUMB')
WHERE
    r.edit_state = 0
    AND r.journal_id = 515
    AND r.journal_table_id = 1
ORDER BY
    r.PRIMARY_DATE DESC;
```